# How to store String type of array values in to HashMap object

Tags: java, spring-mvc

When i try to store String array value to the hashmap it will show null value.please give any solution.thanks in advance

```
                String temp;
                String[] line=new String[15];
                Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();

                InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(path);
BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                while((temp = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<line.length ;j++)
                    {   
                        line[j]=reader.readLine();

                        String fname=line[0];
                        String lname=line[1];
                        String mobile=line[2];
                        String gender=line[3];

                    //Store array string to map
                        map.put("fname",fname);

                    //retrive map object    
                       System.out.println(map.get(fname));

                System.out.println(fname);//showing null value in console

                System.out.println(lname);//array shows values
                System.out.println(mobile);//array shows values

                    }
```

Comment: `map.get(fname)` - here you need to use the _key_ and not the value, so try `map.get("fname")` instead (see `map.put("fname",fname);` - the key is `"fname"` here)

Comment: Site note: why are you storing the lines inside the loop body where you are filling the array? When the first line has been read you're still calling `String lname=line[1];` and `line[1]` will be null at that time (the same is true for all following lines). Also I'm not sure that loop is correct or at least it doesn't make sense for me: in the while-loop you're reading _one_ line then you're using that line's length to read further lines from the file - why?

Comment: i was tried as you said but it return null values

Comment: and another problem is when i read data from text file it didnt get first line value why?

Comment: Your loops are quite strange and I doubt you want to do that. Instead of that nested for-loop just use the while and add the read lines into a list. Then loop over that list. The problem with the first line is that you're calling `readLine()` in the while and then in the for and that's the one you're storing - `readLine()` will read _one_ line and andvance the cursor so the next call will read the next line.

Comment: here my concern is read text file data line by line and storing that data to the HashMap object. here my text file in local storage and i am using SpringMVC.can you tell me any another process, tanks in advanve

Comment: Well, I already told you what to do: read the lines into a list and then iterate over that list and put whatever you want into that map.

Comment: list means ArrayList ? i am fresher so i am confused please suggest me.

Comment: If you are a Java newbie then I'd strongly suggest getting the basics straight before diving head first into topics like web, ui etc. - you'll save yourself a lot of headaches that way (otherwise you're trying to run when you're bare able to crawl).

Answer (score 0):

You tried to get map value by value (variable fname)

```
 System.out.println("map.get(fname) = "+map.get(fname));
```

but you should use `map.get(key)` and your key is "fname" (as a string) and not fname (as a variable)

the solution is

```
System.out.println("map.get(fname) = "+map.get("fname"));
```

and for FileInputStream try to use file instead of path :

```
 File file = new File("C:/*****");
 InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(file);
```